# I tried to change my x axis on a line graph to just days instead of dates and the line graph has been visualised incorrectly, how to fix it?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I am trying to create a line graph which shows the response times of a go no go trial over a few weeks. However, instead of having the dates on the x axis, I just wanted it to display in the order like 'day 1, day 2' etc... After following advice from another user I added this to my ggplot code

```
 mutate(days = paste0("day",row_number()))
```

The full ggplot code is as follows:

```
p03_dropped_rt %>% 
  mutate(days = paste0("day",row_number())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(days), y = mean, group = trialtype)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title=" P03s Average response time of Go/No-go Trials",
       x = "Day of training",
       y = "Average Response Time ",
       color = "Trial Type")
```

I thought this would change the dates to days and put them in order, however, the produced visualisation is wrong (See picture for clarification)

I am just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to fix this?

here is the data:

```
structure(list(day = structure(c(18880, 18880, 18908, 18908, 
18911, 18912, 18912, 18913, 18913, 18914, 18914, 18915, 18915, 
18916, 18916, 18917, 18917, 18918, 18918, 18919, 18920, 18921, 
18921, 18922, 18922, 18923, 18924), class = "Date"), trialtype = c("go", 
"nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", 
"nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", 
"go", "go", "go", "nogo", "go", "nogo", "go", "go"), mean = c(0.453363414634146, 
0.21005, 0.63720350877193, 0.8809, 0.624077192982456, 0.581956842105263, 
0.63065, 0.588196842105263, 0.607075, 0.540253289473684, 0.73215, 
0.529153097345133, 0.583133333333333, 0.538794736842105, 0.4409, 
0.522421428571429, 0.4792, 0.552129824561403, 0.5282, 0.512742105263158, 
0.473664912280702, 0.528580701754386, 0.544266666666667, 0.490643859649123, 
0.49955, 0.440738596491228, 0.475708771929825)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -27L), groups = structure(list(
    day = structure(c(18880, 18908, 18911, 18912, 18913, 18914, 
    18915, 18916, 18917, 18918, 18919, 18920, 18921, 18922, 18923, 
    18924), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4, 
        5L, 6:7, 8:9, 10:11, 12:13, 14:15, 16:17, 18:19, 20L, 
        21L, 22:23, 24:25, 26L, 27L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -16L), .drop = TRUE))
```

picture of line graph: [image: 1]

Comment: Try adding `group = trialtype` inside `geom_line(aes())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `p03_dropped_rt` was grouped by day earlier, so when you applied your `mutate`, it labeled each "go" trial as day1 and each "nogo" trial as day2. Instead, we can group by trialtype, arrange by day, and then mutate:

```
p03_dropped_rt %>% 
  group_by(trialtype) %>% 
  arrange(day) %>% 
  mutate(days = paste0("day",row_number())) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_inorder(days), y = mean, group = trialtype)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = trialtype)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title=" P03s Average response time of Go/No-go Trials",
       x = "Day of training",
       y = "Average Response Time ",
       color = "Trial Type")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! ive been stuck on this for so long so i really appreciate you helping me out with this one!!! :)